# ngClass mixed condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to implement the following - I want two pre-set classes, which are completed by some component variables I have set, which is working fine, but I need to add another [conditional class](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

This is what I have, first part is working, the object part is not:

`[ngClass]="['btn-' + buttonStyle, 'btn-' + buttonSize, {'btn-rounded': isRounded}]"`

Where ***`isRounded`*** is a component `@Input()`.

`@Input() isRounded: boolean = false;`

End result that I am aiming for:

`<a class="btn btn-success btn-md btn-rounded">okay</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both arrays and objects in `ngClass` at the same time (See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20232)). Instead, you can just use a combination of `class` and `ngClass` or use a ternary condition.

Using `class` and `ngClass`.

```html
<button [class]="'btn-' + buttonStyle + ' btn-' + buttonSize" [ngClass]="{'btn-rounded': isRounded}">Test</button>
```

Using ternary condition in `ngClass`.

```html
<button [ngClass]="['btn-' + buttonStyle, 'btn-' + buttonSize, isRounded ? 'btn-rounded' : '']">Test</button>
```

Comment: The ternary condition did the part. Thank You!

Comment: You could create a directive that accepted nested arrays an objects, but it probably wouldn't be a great idea.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - That's not going to add any value so that would just be tedious and superfluous.

Comment: I was just making the point that it's not an inherent limitation. I agree that it's ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```js
 this.btnClassList = {
      [`btn-${this.buttonStyle}`]: true,
      [`btn-${this.buttonSize}`]: true,
      [`btn-rounded`]: this.isRounded,
}
```

and in template

```html
<a [ngClass]="btnClassList">okay</a>
```

[stack blitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrg37c)